# Double insert after is permitted, but before doesnt

Tags: javascript, html

The following `html` markup

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

and `JS` code

```
function doThis(){
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit.nextSibling);
    myKeys=[];
    myKeys.push(getAllKeyValuePair(submit));
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;
}
function getAllKeyValuePair(obj){
    var str="";
    for(var key in obj){
        try{
            str=str+"{"+key+", "+obj[key]+"}";
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(key);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/9/) example.
It works fine and it's ok to click 2,3,...etcetera times on submit button, to click on duplcate of submit button... etc. But if we trying to replace `child.insertBefore(span,submit.nextSibling);` to `child.insertBefore(span,submit);` (i.e. insert `span` before `submit` button rather than after) we can only 1 time to click to submit button. Consequent clicks will caused exception. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/8/)**

The question obviously is why in the case of inserting before `submit` second and consequent clicks will causes exception, but in the case of insert after `submit` it's work fine. I think, that the reason of duplicating the submit `button` is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
span.innerHTML = myKeys;
```

you're creating another element with `id="submit"`. The next time you click the button,

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
```

assigns this element to the variable, rather than the one in the original HTML. This element is not a child of `child`, so you get an error.

The version with `nextSibling` also creates these duplicate IDs, but the original `submit` element is earlier in the DOM than the added elements, so it gets returned by `getElementById` and you don't get an error. I don't think there's any guarantee that this will work, since duplicate IDs aren't permitted, but it's how most browsers work.

If you don't want the string returned by `getAllKeyValuePairs` to be parsed as HTML, assign it to `span.innerText` rather than `span.innerHTML`.